# Gower and Cosine distances in k means clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to understand some basics of the R language. Yesterday, I made up small exercise for myself:

**Clustering in R**

So far, I managed to make some calculations for euclidean and manhattan methods.

```
resultEuclidean <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method = "euclidean");
resultManhattan <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method = "manhattan");
```

I know, that I could also apply some other distances, like: gower or cosine.

```
resultGower <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method="gower");
resultCosine <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method="cosine");
```

**Question:**

Unfortunately, it is not so simple and still, I cannot figure out how to use these two methods for kmeans clustering. Could someone shed some light on this topic?

**Code**

```
# libraries
library(factoextra);
library(cluster);

install.packages("amap");
library(amap);

# dataset
data("multishapes", package = "factoextra");
myData <- multishapes;
myData$shape <- NULL;

# algorithm
resultEuclidean <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method = "euclidean");
resultManhattan <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method = "manhattan");
resultGower <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method="gower");
resultCosine <- Kmeans(myData, 6, method="cosine");
```

Comment: help us help with a dput(head(myData, n = 20)), 20 or a few more bits of data so we can scratch our heads with you. Copy the dput results from your session and edit them into your question. It makes a world of difference, generally.

Answer (score 2):

### k-means minimizes variance, not distance

It is a fairly common misconception that k-means minimizes distances because it "assigns every point to the nearest centroid". But that is only half of k-means. K-means then recomputes the centers, which does *not* minimize other distances, but only very few.

The mean is a least-squares estimator, which minimizes `sum_d (x[d] - center[d])^2`. I.e. it minimizes squared Euclidean.

If you use squared Euclidean also when assigning points to centers, then the method will reliably work and converge.

This puts *severe* limits on what distances can be used with k-means (Bregman divergences). For other distances, there exist e.g. PAM (Partitioning around medoids) where the medoid is the object with the smallest distance (using any metric) to all other cluster members. You can transfer the medoid concept to k-means, by replacing the mean with the medoid. You then get k-medoids.